# How to design a specialised proxy class from a generic proxy.

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns

Consider the following case of a proxy pattern. 
(Not sure this truly is a “proxy pattern”, but I’ll go with it).

I am given a class Dog and a proxy class `DogProxy`, which modify/extends a `Dog`'s functionality and is a `Dog` itself

```
class DogProxy : public Dog
```

The proxy class has a public method

```
void DogProxy::setSource(Dog *)
```

which is called to “plug” the proxy onto a specific `Dog` object.

`DogProxy` is given and ready to use, and I am also given another (non proxy) subclass

```
class GermanShepard : public Dog.
```

I need to implement a new proxy class which is specialised to be used use with and only with a `GermanShepard`.

Such `GermanShepardProxy` should have

```
void GermanShepardProxy::setSource(GermanShepard *)
```

instead of the generic `setSource(Dog *)`, although this is not a constraint, it just seems to me to make sense.

I would like `GermanShepardProxy` to be implemented in terms of `DogProxy`, which already contains most of the functionality.

I could publicly inherit from `DogProxy`, but in doing so I have an inconsistency, because hiding `DogProxy::setSource(Dog *)`
violates the principle that `GermanShepardProxy` is a `DogProxy`.
I could use protected inheritance instead, but then `GermanShepardProxy` would not be a `Dog` anymore and therefore quite useless.

To summarize: given `Dog`, `DogProxy` and `GermanShepard` as above, how can I effectively design a `GermanShepardProxy`, which should be a `Dog` but not a `DogProxy`?

Answer (score 0):

> I could publicly inherit from DogProxy, but in doing so I have an
>   inconsistency, because hiding DogProxy::setSource(Dog *) violates the
>   principle that GermanShepardProxy is a DogProxy.

If, as you say, `GermandShepardProxy` is a `DogProxy`, then `GermanShepardProxy` must implement `setSource(Dog *)`. Because that's what a `DogProxy` is.

Your stated objectives are in conflict with each other. If `GermandShepardProxy` is a `DogProxy`, then this method is implemented. If not, then it's not.

Sounds to me like you need to refactor your class hierarchy. The immediate subclass of `Dog` should probably not be your `DogProxy`, but something else that has all the common, shared functionality of the two proxies. Then, `DogProxy` subclasses that, and implements just its `setSource()` method, and `GermandShepardProxy` also subclasses it, and implements just its own `setSource()` method.

Comment: I said `GermanShepardProxy` should be a `Dog`, otherwise there is clearly inconsistency. I cannot refactor the class hierarchy unfortunately, I am looking for a consistent way to design `GermanShepardProxy` given such hierarchy.

Comment: Well, C++ is C++. It is what it is. If you must absolutely have this hierarchy, then, either you hide setSource() in the superclass, or make it a virtual method, and in the GermanShepardProxy::setSource() use dynamic_cast<>, throwing a runtime exception if the object is not a GermanShepard. I see no other options.

Comment: I think there might be some clever approach that does not just consist in subclassing. I am now trying to reason along the line of subclassing from `Dog` and than adding a `DogProxy` member to use as a private implementation... let's see if I get to something meaningful.